# Using RefineryCMS and the Theming Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I am in the beginning stages of diving into the world of RefineryCMS and am having an issue with the theming Engine.

I was able to customize the look of the home and blog pages, but for individual pages I create outside of the home and blog engine are not falling under the normal theme I created. I used the override method to copy all of the necessary files to my custom theme, but like I said, the page is using the default /pages/show.html.erb file vs the theme/mytheme/pages/show.html.erb file..

Any ideas on why this would be happening?

Comment: Unless you intend to reuse the theme it can be easier to start with RefineryCMS without using the theming engine and using app/views/ and public/ instead.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I don't know why I started off customizing a theme in the first place... I should have just modified the root files and been done with it..

Answer (score 1):

The use of the theming engine is not recommended anymore:

> USE OF THE REFINERYCMS-THEMING GEM IS NO LONGER RECOMMENDED. Why?
>   Theming performs some strange code hacks in order to get it to work.
>   Therefore, it makes it difficult to keep it compatible with other
>   engines. Also, many people have reported over 15 second load times
>   with theming, whereas regularly you would get 3 second load times.
>   Finally, Resolve Digital no longer uses nor supports this method.

https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-theming